# Asymptotic expansion for the solution of linear KDV eq.

Tags: asymptotics, taylor-expansion, fourier-series, wave-equation

## Hi,

The question arises from the book Solitons by P. G. Drazin about the linearized KDV eq. 
$$
    u_t+u_{xxx}=0
$$
My first step was to take a Fourier transform of the equation, find that the dispersion relation was $-\alpha^3$ and then to have a Fourier expansion of the form
$$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i(kx+k^3t)}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-iky}dydk $$
then by playing around with $k=\alpha/(3t)^{1/3}$ I get the following terms

\begin{align}
u(x,t)&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{u_0(y)}{(3t)^{1/3}}dy\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i(\alpha\frac{x-y}{(3t)^{1/3}}+\frac{\alpha^3}{3})}d\alpha\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{u_0(y)}{(3t)^{1/3}}\Bigg[\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i(\alpha\frac{x}{(3t)^{1/3}}+\frac{\alpha^3}{3})}d\alpha-\frac{y}{(3t)^{1/3}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\alpha e^{i(\alpha\frac{x}{(3t)^{1/3}}+\frac{\alpha^3}{3})}d\alpha\Bigg]dy+\dots
\end{align}
where, to arrive at the second expression, we need to use taylor expansion for $exp(-iky)$.
Now, I'm trying to find an asymptotic expansion in the area $x/t^{1/3}\approx O(1)$, for $x>0$ and $x<0$ separately...
Drazin's book states that $x<0$ should be "a slowly decaying wave train" and $0<x$ should be "a steeply rising wave front" 
But i don't know how to arrive at that.

Could anyone lend a hand with the task?

### edit:

After awhile trying to find the asymptotics using the asymptotics or $Ai(x)$ I've come to the conclusion that it is not the way since they are based on $\frac{x}{(3t)^{1/3}}\to\infty$ and are so useless to my effort. 
thus focusing on
\begin{align}
u(x,t)&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{u_0(y)}{(3t)^{1/3}}dy\cdot Ai(\frac{x}{(3t)^{1/3}})-\int_{-\infty}^\infty y\frac{u_0(y)}{(3t)^{2/3}}dy\cdot Ai'(\frac{x}{(3t)^{1/3}})+\dots
\end{align}
I've decided to look for the asymptotics for fixed $v=\frac{x}{(3t)^{1/3}}=o(1)$
which leads to: 
\begin{align}
u(v(3t)^{1/3},t)&=\frac{v}{x}\int_{-\infty}^\infty u_0(y)dy\cdot Ai(v)-\frac{v^2}{x^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty y\cdot u_0(y)dy\cdot Ai'(v)+\dots
\end{align}

does anyone have an idea how to continue?

Comment: This kind of integrals i quite common if you try to approximate solutions to complicated differential equations. I  would suggest you look up "Airy functions"

Comment: @tired I have looked into the conection to the Airy function Ai, as was also suggested in the book...the solution can be rewritten as:
\begin{align}
u(x,t)
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{u_0(y)}{(3t)^{1/3}}\Bigg[Ai(\frac{x}{(3t)^\frac{1}{3}})-\frac{y}{(3t)^{1/3}}Ai'(\frac{x}{(3t)^\frac{1}{3}})\Bigg]dy+\dots
\end{align}

but I haven't found a good asymptotic approximation anywhere, do you have an example perchance?

Comment: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/notes/asy.pdf for example....
Chapter 3.4.1 is exactl what u need

Comment: Thanks so much, looking into it!

Comment: @tired Thanks again, as it turns out this particular approximation isn't good for my purpuse since it works with the assumption of fixed $v=x/t$ where as I need fixed $c=\frac{x}{(3t)^{1/3}}$...
do you know where i can find something in that range?